# Import throws "Could not load file or assembly"

Tags: export, import

We've exported a web site on SP2010 using this command:

```
Export-SPWeb -Identity http://vmdev95/ -Path \\vmdev95\sp_backup\acm -NoFileCompression -HaltOnError -HaltOnWarning -IncludeUserSecurity
```

Then we're trying to import it using this command:

```
Import-SPWeb -Identity http://vmdev199:2021/ -Path \\vmdev95\sp_backup\acm -NoFileCompression -ActivateSolutions -HaltOnError -HaltOnWarning -IncludeUserSecurity
```

It throws this error:

```
Warning: Cannot update event receiver because: Could not load file or assembly 'DocAve.SP2010.Replicator.Eventhandler, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=33f79f916929c512' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
[31-Oct-11 4:44:27 PM] FatalError: Cannot update event receiver because: Could not load file or assembly 'DocAve.SP2010.Replicator.Eventhandler, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=33f79f916929c512' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
[31-Oct-11 4:44:27 PM] Debug:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.DeploymentLogger.Log(DeploymentLogSeverity severity, SPLoggerObject loggerObject, SPDeploymentObject deplObject, String message, Boolean throwException)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.EventReceiverSerializer.UpdateEventReceiver(SPEventReceiverDefinition eventReceiver, XmlElement eventReceiverData)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.EventReceiverSerializer.SetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.WebSerializer.UpdateEventReceivers(String tagReceivers, SPWeb web, SerializationInfoHelper infoHelper, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.WebSerializer.SetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.CallSetObjectData(Object obj, SerializationInfo objectData, ISerializationSurrogate surrogate, ISurrogateSelector selector)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.ParseObject(Type objectType, Boolean isChildObject)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.DeserializeObject(Type objectType, Boolean isChildObject, DeploymentObject envelope)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ObjectSerializer.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.DeserializeObjects()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPImport.Run()
[31-Oct-11 4:44:27 PM] Progress: Import did not complete.
[31-Oct-11 4:44:27 PM] Finish Time: 31-Oct-11 4:44:27 PM.
[31-Oct-11 4:44:27 PM] Duration: 00:03:04
[31-Oct-11 4:44:27 PM] Finished with 1 warnings.
[31-Oct-11 4:44:27 PM] Finished with 1 errors.
```

We had DocAve demo installed but uninstalled it; regardless, it was throwing the error even before uninstalling it.

Any ideas what's going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you removed DocAve already, the solutions bits were probably removed but it appears they were not un-registered with SharePoint.

You need to ensure all the DocAve solution features are unregistered and removed from the farm.  You can use CA, Powershell, or a tool like feature admin from codeplex to assist: http://featureadmin.codeplex.com/

Then re-accomplish the export / import.

Additionally have you just tried the import without the `-haltonerror`and `-haltonwarning` parameters?  You will still want to cleanup the orphaned feature(s), but you may be able to get away without re-accomplishing the export.